# Wiring: Replace light switch with GCL switch/outlet

Tags: wiring, switch

Is this the correct wiring to replace an old light switch with a GCL outlet/switch.

The Left is the existing wiring, the right is what I think it should be.

Did i get this right?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is GFC and GCL?

Comment: I take it a you're trying to replace the existing switch with a *GFCI* switch/outlet?

Comment: Why do you want a GFCI on a lighting circuit?